# Java Rectangle intersections

Tags: java, intersection

Will java count rectangles, one of which is inside th other as intersecting, and return an intersection which is the smaller rectangle when I call intersection(Rectangle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Returns**:
    the largest `Rectangle` contained in both the specified `Rectangle` and in this `Rectangle`

As far as I understand you case, the result would be the smaller `Rectangle` that is contained in the larger one.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> import java.awt.Rectangle
import java.awt.Rectangle

scala> val big = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10)
big: java.awt.Rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=10,height=10]

scala> val small = new Rectangle(2, 2, 3, 3)
small: java.awt.Rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle[x=2,y=2,width=3,height=3]

scala> big.intersection(small)
res0: java.awt.Rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle[x=2,y=2,width=3,height=3]

scala> small.intersection(big)
res1: java.awt.Rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle[x=2,y=2,width=3,height=3]
```